# How can I limit text box width of QLineEdit to display at most four characters?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qlineedit

I am working with a GUI based on PySide. I made a (one line) text box with `QLineEdit` and the input is just four characters long, a restriction I already successfully applied.

The problem is I have a wider than needed text box (i.e. there is a lot of unused space after the text). How can I shorten the length of the text box?

I know this is something that is easily fixed by designing the text box with Designer; however, this particular text box is not created in Designer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you want is modify your `QLineEdit` width and fix it, use:

```py
#setFixedWidth(int w)
MyLineEdit.setFixedWidth(120)
```

Comment: Do you know how I can use this in combination with " layout.addWidget(QLineEdit(), 0, 0) " ?

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the [source](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/widgets/qlineedit.cpp) of `QLineEdit.sizeHint()` one sees that a line edit is typically wide enough to display 17 latin "x" characters. I tried to replicate this in Python and change it to display 4 characters but I failed in getting the style dependent margins of the line edit correctly due to limitations of the Python binding of Qt.

A simple:

```
e = QtGui.QLineEdit()
fm = e.fontMetrics()
m = e.textMargins()
c = e.contentsMargins()
w = 4*fm.width('x')+m.left()+m.right()+c.left()+c.right()
```

is returning 24 in my case which however is not  enough to display four characters like "abcd" in a QLineEdit. A better value would be about 32 which you can set for example like.

```
e.setMaximumWidth(w+8) # mysterious additional factor required
```

which might still be okay even if the font is changed on many systems.

Comment: The extra eight pixels are coming from the `2*d->horizontalMargin` and the frame. The mysterious `horizontalMargin` and `verticalMargin` values are static constants found in [qlineedit_p.cpp](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/widgets/qlineedit_p.cpp#n57), and are set to `2` and `1` respectively. The frame values are calculated by the style. So we have `2 * 2` (*horizonal margin*) plus `2 * 2` (*frame*) equals eight. With the exception of the constants, I was able to port all of the `sizeHint` code to pyside and verify the calculation.